# Double back button on UINavigationController when navigating from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

Good day

I'm developing an app for displaying pdf files. I have two viewController, ListViewController for listing all my pdfs and PdfViewController for viewing a pdf. So , when Im importing a pdf file from external app , I save it immediately in app delegate in method called   `application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`

and navigate to PdfViewController .

My problem now is: If I have a pdf already in view (PdfViewController), when Im pushing from the appDelegate to PdfViewController it adds the stack on top and create a double back button to listViewController. Here is my code from the app delegate below.

```
_window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
            UIViewController *root = [_window rootViewController];
            UIStoryboard *stbd = root.storyboard;

PTPdfViewController *viewController = (PTPdfViewController*) [stbd 

instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PTPdfViewController"];

[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController 

pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

How could I replace the current opened pdfViewController with the current pushed one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just pop to root view controller with animation:No & Push to pdfcontroller. 
Or
 just check if the current view controller is pdfcontroller  just replace the file in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by two ways.

1. First pop to root view controller & then push to `pdfviewcontroller` again. (Bad idea)
2. Get the Root view controller , Get the current visible view controller And if its already in `pdfViewcontroller` , just replace the old file with currentfile. If  current view controller is `listviewcontroller` , just push to `pdfviewcontroller`

Getting Visible view controller

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.visibleViewController` to get the currently displayed VC.

Comment: Prada Hota thank you so much, now Im able to see which view is visible and replace it if necessary or just update the content. Thanks